# Excel Formula Conditioning

Tags: excel

I am stuck at a formula.

My requirement is:

if cell c7 = $g$2 then 10 & c6 <= 0 add 10 in c7 value & if not then 0

What I want to achieve is I am preparing graph in which data will fill automatically but start time will vary.
So $g$2 is the time selection (already defined) when it matched numbers will start from there..

```
eg.   $g$2 = 08:50

08:00   0
08:10   0
08:20   0
08:30   0
08:40   0
08:50   10
09:00   20
09:10   30
09:20   40


if $g$2 = 8:00

08:00   10
08:10   20
08:20   30
08:30   40
08:40   50
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Considering that your data starts from C5 Cell and this formula will be in D5

```
=IF(C5<$G$2,0,D4+10)
```

Please check and let me know if it works.